# ...you use me everyday to find your way

Tags: riddle, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**A list of words (one is a possessive noun) is missing. There is only one list that's correct. Can you find it?**

---

*I am round, have a twin and you use me everyday to find your way.*

*I am round, very bright and you see me as a tiny dot when in reality I am extremely large.*

*I look like your best friend, the one that's part of your family, but I'm wild and only to be found down under.*

*I am owned and used daily by a lot of people all over the world. I need some type of fuel to function and it's common that people want me to look fancy.*

*I am what some guys do to a pan to demonstrate their strength.*

*I am related to heat but I'm also contained in the name of a greedy animated character from a very popular sitcom.*

*I am a very well known city and people seem to love me, it says so on their t-shirts.*

```
       [+][+][+][][][-]       
       [][][][-][+][+][+][+]     
       [+][+][+][][][][][-]   
       [-][][][+][+][+][+][+]       
       [+][+][+][-][][][]     
       [+][+][+][-][][][]    
       [+][+][+][][][-]
```

---

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First to answer the clues...

> *I am round, have a twin and you use me everyday to find your way.* = **EYE**
>
>  *I am round, very bright and you see me as a tiny dot when in reality I am extremely large.* = **STAR**
>
>  *I look like your best friend, the one that's part of your family, but I'm wild and only to be found down under.* = **DINGO**
>
>  *I am owned and used daily by a lot of people all over the world. I need some type of fuel to function and it's common that people want me to look fancy.* = **CAR**
>
>  *I am what some guys do to a pan to demonstrate their strength.* = **BEND**
>
>  *I am related to heat but I'm also contained in the name of a greedy animated character from a very popular sitcom.* = **BURN** (from [Mr Burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Burns) in *The Simpsons*)
>
>  *I am a very well known city and people seem to love me, it says so on their t-shirts.* = **NYC** (New York City)

We now need to manipulate these words to form other words in a set. The 7 sets of square brackets with '+' and '-' symbols explain how:

> Matching each word to its respectively ordered 'bracket row', the word should be positioned in the spaces that do not contain '+' symbols. Then wherever there is a '-' symbol, the letter should be deleted.
>
>  We are then left with 7 half-deciphered words as follows:
>
>  [+][+][+][E][Y]
>  [S][T][A][+][+][+][+]
>  [+][+][+][D][I][N][G]
>  [A][R][+][+][+][+][+]
>  [+][+][+][E][N][D]
>  [+][+][+][U][R][N]
>  [+][+][+][N][Y]

We now suspect that we need to find a set of related words (likely a *complete* set) that can probably be put into the bracketed spaces containing '+' symbols to form other real words. This can be done if we use...

> ...the **7 days of the week** - specifically, MON, TUES, WED, THURS, FRI, SAT and SUN:
>
>  **[M][O][N]**[E][Y]
>  [S][T][A]**[T][U][E][S]**
>  **[W][E][D]**[D][I][N][G]
>  [A][R]**[T][H][U][R]'[S]** (this is the possessive noun mentioned in the puzzle)
>  **[F][R][I]**[E][N][D]
>  **[S][A][T]**[U][R][N]
>  **[S][U][N]**[N][Y]

And the puzzle is complete!

Comment: That's crazy, almost exactly the same time :D I just made a small change to make it consistent. The 6th one. Missed letters. But if you could just change that it would be great. Good job, and nicely explained!

Comment: You know what, nvm. I'll edit back to the previous post. Realized it won't work for 3rd either.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ha, how funny! I imagine the alternative was possibly rot13(TNGR naq FNGHENGR), but then of course yes number 3 causes some issues!

Comment: That was exactly it.  Yes, so I'll just let it be as it is. And also, in the title, I tried to sneak in a suiting word related to this puzzle.